# Laravel 8 define belongsToMany definition in Model factory

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-8, factory

I'm trying to create a `Request` factory that will assign multiple random users for every individual `Request` instance that is created using said factory.

using the method `definition` in the Factory I am able to assign a `belongsTo` for `Media`, but it's not clear to me how I can create a `belongsToMany` for `users`.

This is my `Request` model:

```
class Request extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function media()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Media');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

This is the Factory that I have right now:

```
class RequestFactory extends Factory
{

    protected $model = Request::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            // This is the belongsToMany relationship (that doesn't work) defined as users() in the Request model.
            'users' => function() {
                return User::inRandomOrder()->random(random_int(1,5))->get()->pluck('id');
            },
            // This is the belongsTo relationship (that works)
            'media_id' => function() {
                return Media::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

Aside of the key `users` I also tried `user_id` & `User::class` hoping that Laravel would pick up on the array, and automatically use it in the relationship, but unfortunately that didn't work either since that column doesn't exist.

How can I make this work specifically from within the factory?

Comment: When you do this, you have to literally specify the column, so if you have a `users` `belongsTo` relation, then you should have a `user_id`, same for `media`, it should be `media_id`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I want `users` to be a `belongsToMany`, not a `belongsTo`.

Comment: I am sorry, I misread that one. Then you can't specify it there, it is only for columns. You have to use the [After creation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-callbacks).

Comment: You can be doing this in your tests, which makes more sense in a lot of cases. `Request::factory()->hasUsers(4)->hasMedia()->create();` This will create a `Request` with 4 `User` and 1 `Media` relationship, using the factory methods for those models.

Comment: I had that, but I am using UUIDs and for whatever reason, rather then using existing models, it seemed to generate random UUIDs that didn't exist causing the foreign key constraints to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think when you do a belongToMany Relation, there is another table between Request and User which can be called UserRequest, You cant specified it in a Factory like this, but you can create a after create function to create the link between the users and the request in the third table
You can see it here on documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-callbacks

You can add this following method in your factory class:

```
public function configure()
{
    return $this->afterMaking(function (Request $request) {
        //
    })->afterCreating(function (Request $request) {
        //
    });
}
```